Text conversion processing and extracting information
I have a call center software which consist of industry specific calls, in which all calls are recorded and then all calls transform into text. After transforming into text, every calls is passed to other agent who is human, who extract all information from text. I have to extract information from AI, or some sort of services and analyze conversation between two if them, then save it in DB.
Let say a call center person name is Bob and the person whom need assisstance from bob is foo. the conversation between the two person is below.
Bob : Hey Foo, I am Bob, How may I help you today?
Foo: Hey, I am good, I have a issue with product which I have purchased from you.

Bob : We never like to hear customers are unhappy. Why don’t you start by giving me your full name and order number so I can try to address this issue for you?
Foo : Yeah, it is a electric bike, and Number is BBM-3344.

and so on...

Now I have to extract all information from conversation like

sentiments (light or harsh mood, happy or sad etc.)
filler words (um, ha, etc words)
confident level
answer is appropriate, answer related to topic
engagements (engagement between the two)
talk time
conversation topic
Number of questions asked.

and all other information.
Now my questions are:

What information we extract from conversation other than that?
How to extract all information from python and their libraries/packages?

